# Deployed dolly2 model in Sagemaker for embeddings, but receiving a 400 error when calling endpoint

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed the dolly2 model in sagemaker and I am trying to create some vectors for embeddings, the code works just fine for text generation but after changing the inference.py to handle embeddings, I am getting the error below

```
otocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "(\"You need to define one of the following [\u0027audio-classification\u0027, \u0027automatic-speech-recognition\u0027, \u0027feature-extraction\u0027, \u0027text-classification\u0027, \u0027token-classification\u0027, \u0027question-answering\u0027, \u0027table-question-answering\u0027, \u0027visual-question-answering\u0027, \u0027document-question-answering\u0027, \u0027fill-mask\u0027, \u0027summarization\u0027, \u0027translation\u0027, \u0027text2text-generation\u0027, \u0027text-generation\u0027, \u0027zero-shot-classification\u0027, \u0027zero-shot-image-classification\u0027, \u0027conversational\u0027, \u0027image-classification\u0027, \u0027image-segmentation\u0027, \u0027image-to-text\u0027, \u0027object-detection\u0027, \u0027zero-shot-object-detection\u0027, \u0027depth-estimation\u0027, \u0027video-classification\u0027] as env \u0027HF_TASK\u0027.\", 403)"
}
```

Below you can also see the code that I am using for the embedding

```
import json
import os
import boto3
from transformers import pipeline


def invoke_sagemaker_endpoint():
    # Create a SageMaker client
    sagemaker_client = boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime")

    # Define the endpoint name and payload
    endpoint_name = 'XXX'  # Replace with your SageMaker endpoint name
    payload = {"inputs": "This is a large document."}  # Update the payload format as expected by the model

    # Send the request to the SageMaker endpoint
    response = sagemaker_client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName=endpoint_name,
        ContentType="application/json",
        Body=json.dumps(payload),
    )

    # Parse the response and extract the embeddings vector
    response_body = response["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")
    response_json = json.loads(response_body)

    if "embeddings" in response_json:
        embeddings = response_json["embeddings"]
        embeddings_vector = embeddings[0]  # embeddings are returned as a list
        return embeddings_vector
    else:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set the HF_TASK environment variable to 'feature-extraction' for the embeddings
    os.environ["HF_TASK"] = "feature-extraction"
    # Invoke the SageMaker endpoint
    embeddings_vector = invoke_sagemaker_endpoint()

    if embeddings_vector:
        print(embeddings_vector)
    else:
        print("No embeddings found in the response.")
```

and the inference.py

```
import torch
from transformers import pipeline

def model_fn(model_dir):
    model = pipeline(
        "text-generation",
        model=model_dir,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        trust_remote_code=True,
        device_map="auto",
        model_kwargs={"load_in_8bit": True},
    )
    tokenizer = model.tokenizer
    embeddings_model = model.model

    def generate_embeddings(inputs):
        inputs = tokenizer(inputs, truncation=True, padding="longest", return_tensors="pt")
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = embeddings_model(**inputs)
        embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).squeeze(0).tolist()
        return embeddings

    def retrieve_qa(question, context):
        inputs = {"question": question, "context": context}
        qa_outputs = model(question, context)
        return qa_outputs

    return model, generate_embeddings, retrieve_qa
```

Changed the inference, the HF, redeployed to sagemaker, called from api gateway instead of sagemaker endpoint

Comment: Can you try changing the HF_TASK env variable value to text_generation. Looks like you are doing text_generation and then returning the value of the last hidden state.

Answer (score 1):

Hey [Arpel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13038760/arpel), it seems you are mixing two different methods of deploying Hugging Face models as SageMaker Endpoints.

For future reference, I see you have tried to set the `HF_TASK` environment variable, however, you're doing it on the instance used to call boto3 — this is *separate* from the instance that will host your model and perform inference. Follow this guide for the specifics on **non-custom** inference with SageMaker and HuggingFace.

Because you'd like the model to perform two tasks — embeddings and QA — you're correct in identifying that you'll need a custom `inference.py` file. To take this approach, you'll need to perform the following steps:

- Clone the model from Hugging Face using git
- Create a `code/` directory (within the model dir) and add an `inference.py` file
- Include two functions in the inference file, these **must** be called `model_fn()` and `predict_fn()`. The former is used only when the endpoint is initialised, and must return the model & tokeniser, the latter is called for each inference request. You can use the `predict_fn()` to include custom logic.
- Create a tarball (`model.tar.gz`) with all the model artefacts (incl. your custom inference code). It should be formatted as below.

```
model.tar.gz/
|- pytorch_model.bin
|- ....
|- code/
  |- inference.py
  |- requirements.txt
```

- Finally, upload the tarball to S3 and pass the S3 URI to SageMaker when creating a model/endpoint.

There's a great [notebook from Hugging Face](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/17_custom_inference_script/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb) covering this whole process. It's the best guide I've been able to find so far. If you copy it word-for-word, and only modify the `inference.py` script, you should be successful.

Here's an example of an `inference.py` I've used previously, as you can see, Hugging Face Pipelines work too!

```py
from transformers import pipeline, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from DirectQuoteUtils import reformat
import torch
import os

def model_fn(model_dir):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)
    model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_dir)
    pipe = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
    return pipe

def predict_fn(data, pipeline):
    pipe = pipeline
    outputs = []
    
    # FORMAT FOR MODEL INPUT:
    # {               # list of strings
    #     "inputs": ["Donald Trump is the president of the US", "Joe Biden is the United States president"]
    # }
    
    modelData = pipe(data['inputs'])
    
    for prediction in modelData:
        cleanPred = reformat(prediction)
        outputs.append(cleanPred)
        
    return {
        # "device": device, # handy to check if CUDA is being used
        "outputs": outputs
    }
```

Comment: Hi fucalhost, that did not seem to solve my problem unfortunately, I have pivoted and used both endpoint either straight or through a wrapper and changed the inference but the issue persists. I had to utilise the previous version and then deployed another model to handle the embeddings.

Comment: hey @Arpel, could you edit the question and provide the new error message?