# AttributeError: module 'torch.nn.init' has no attribute 'trunc_normal_' While saving trasnformer google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k model to local

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface

I am trying to save `google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k` locally and then upload it to s3 for hosting this model in the SageMaker environment.

```
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, ViTModel
# tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
# model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

# processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")
model = ViTModel.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")

model_path = "model/"
code_path = "code/"

if not os.path.exists(model_path):
    os.mkdir(model_path)
    
model.save_pretrained(save_directory=model_path)
# processor.save_pretrained(save_directory=model_path)
```

Getting below error while saving

```
AttributeError: module 'torch.nn.init' has no attribute 'trunc_normal_'
```

I tried modifying the transformer library version with no luck. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using `conda_amazonei_pytorch_latest_p37` kernel in sagemaker.

Reference: https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker-script-mode/pytorch_bert/deploy_bert_outputs.html

Comment: Hey  are you using the specified version of transformers? The linked notebook requires `transformers==3.3.1`. Try running `%pip list` in the notebook. [Here’s a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76417315/19375186) for HF models in SageMaker, let me know how you get on. Good luck!