# Sagemaker-An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message

Tags: deployment, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

```
# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge', # ec2 instance type
    serializer=JSONSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer(),
)
```

from PIL import Image

# Open an image file

test1 = Image.open('test.jpg')

import base64

img_base64 = base64.b64encode(test1.tobytes()).decode('utf-8')

predictor.predict(data=img_base64)

---

The following error returned:

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "\u0027str\u0027 object has no attribute \u0027pop\u0027"
}
```

Comment: Check your CloudWatch logs if there is a more detailed error message

Answer (score 1):

Hey [lazybot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22749436/lazybot)

I understand you're using the SageMaker Python SDK to deploy a Hugging Face model to a SageMaker endpoint, and it looks like the model does ~something~ with image data based on your use of PIL.

Given your use of images, the `JSONSerializer` seems to be the wrong option here. If you use the [DataSerializer](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/serializers.html#sagemaker.base_serializers.DataSerializer), the raw bites of an image file can be sent to your endpoint.

This requires, however, use of a custom `inference.py` file ([learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76380739/deployed-dolly2-model-in-sagemaker-for-embeddings-but-receiving-a-400-error-whe/76417315#76417315)), that might look like the following:

```py
import io
import torch
from PIL import Image
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

DEVICE = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

def model_fn(model_dir: str)
    model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_dir)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)
    model = model.to(DEVICE)

def predict_fn(data):
    # serialize bytes to PIL.Image
    image_data = ... # byte values of the image
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
    # ... your model inference code ...
    return {
        "outputs": ...,
        "device": DEVICE
    }
```

Good luck!!